# Analog Sensor output signal accuracy and sensitivity

Tags: sensor, analog, load-cell

I have to decide between 2 load cell models. the only difference between the two is  that the output on one is 2mV/V and the other is 3mV/V. Both are rated at 2.5klbs.
Which one of them would be more accurate with less fluctuations? 
[image]

Comment: Sensitivity and precision are two completely different attributes. Link the datasheets (or at least identify the sensors) and then explain your specific application.

Comment: @PeterSmith  These are coming in from china. So obviously i have no details what so ever. But i am going to include the cut sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about **accuracy** then look for the error specifications in the datasheet. The accuracy is not necessarily correlated with the sensitivity. However, if you **really** care about accuracy then you will only buy from an established manufacturer that can tell you about how they test their devices and how they calibrate their test equipment.

The "fluctuations" in sensor output will be due to the physical and electrical stuff that you put around the sensor. You won't get that from a data sheet. If you care about long term drift then look for those specifications in the datasheet. If the manufacturer won't tell you and back it up then look for a different manufacturer.

If you insist on buying undocumented equipment from unreputable suppliers then it is **your** responsibility to characterize and calibrate the sensors. Buy a few extra and do long term life testing so you know what the drift will be.

Comment: Right. Understood.
So what difference would it make to the system with 2 different voltage outputs? how is one different to the other?

Comment: Based on the information provided, the two load cells are different in that their scale factors (the sensitivity) are different. When you convert voltage to mass you need to take that into consideration. Get the datasheets. Compare the datasheets.